# What html tag best to use with sprites

Tags: css, css-sprites

I would like to use sprites to display my icons. I created image and CSS, now I need to add class to my html element. What is the best HTML element for that?

`<div>` works fine, but of course it spans across entire space and wraps.  works only if I put something in it. Here's my CSS

```
.sprite {
    background:url('/i/sprites.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat
}
.ico2{
    background-position:0 -104px;
    width:16px;
    height:16px
}
```

Answer (score 4):

My opinion is that it doesn't matter. Whatever tags are suitable for the rest of your content.

- `<ul><li></li></ul>` structures are very flexible for layout.
- `<div>` and `<span>`of course.
- I often find myself using sprites for buttons in links.

You'll probably want  to use `display: block` or `display: inline-block` for most of the elements where you put your sprites, and remember that you can set that for all elements.

Comment: I need to debug why my span is not showing... It works fine on test page but not on the live one, so I ended up using <div> with style="float:left". Now, when I used image I often used  align="absmiddle" to align the text following the image to the center of the image. How do i do this with <span> or <div> if I use sprites?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on context. Try to choose the element which best represents the semantics of the data, not on how it will be displayed; that's what CSS is for.

Are you displaying a **list** of icons? Use a `<ul>` and put your sprites in its `<li>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `<span>` tags and set it's display to `inline-block` with defined height and width.

Comment: I believe inline-block is not supported in IE7 and IE6